# Open an additional X session for a new DISPLAY

Tags: x11, tty

I am writing and debugging a Window Manager for X.

I would like to be able to run gdb on my application. The application requires an X display. I want two sessions in parallel: one where I develop, run gdb and the application, and one to which I redirect my application.

I have tried multiple VT.

- login to my development session with gdm
- go to another VT with Ctrl+Alt+F3 (I am using Ubuntu 20.04)
- start a new X session with `sudo X :2`

This last command kills everything else, both my development session in tty2, and the gdm login in tty1. I am left with black screens.

I also tried `startx`, but that opens a Desktop Environment (it looks like gnome). I've tried to modify `~/.xinitrc`, to `unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR && sleep 60`, but then I lost access to my other ttys for the 60 seconds.

`unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR && X :2` does not really fail, but returns immediately.

How can I get a separate X session in a TTY, so that I can run and debug my application from another TTY?

Comment: It looks like the driver of your GPU might not like having multiple instances of itself running at the same time, and doing so perhaps causes your GPU to crash. Are you perhaps using proprietary Nvidia or AMD drivers? Also, `sudo X :2` would not start a complete new X *session*, just a new X *server* with nothing running on it. You would have to manage its session cookie yourself (or disable the X authentication, which is not secure), then start at least a window manager (or a complete desktop environment) on your `:2` display to make it useful.

Comment: Have you considered running your application within a *nested X server* (`Xnest` or `Xephyr`)? Or does the application use DRI or otherwise do something that requires access to the real GPU? (If yes, that is important information that should be added to your question, as that will restrict your options quite a bit.)

Comment: You can run your app with second instance of X server in e.g. tty8 with `xinit /full/path/to/your_app -- :1 vt8`.  Also Xephyr or Xnest may help.

Comment: @telcoM Awesome, I didn't know about Xnest. Now starting it with `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR= Xnest :1`, and my application with `DISPLAY=:1 gdb ./my_app`, and I can hunt my segfault. Thanks! It would still be great to learn what was wrong with my attempt at using the VT...

Comment: @dimich That did not work for me, and above all, I want to run my application through gdb and have debugging access. Would I be able to put gdb in the xinit command, you mean?

Comment: @Gauthier Your application should use `DISPLAY` environment varable to connect to X server. You can run it from anywhere with correct `DISPLAY` variable set.

Comment: @dimich Ok, but how do I start an xserver, of which I can get the DISPLAY variable, in another VT? All while keeping control of the session I develop in.

Comment: @Gauthier For such purposes i run second instance of X server directly from terminal in "main" instance, e.g. in background: `X :1 vt8 &`. Then switch back to "main" X with Ctrl+Alt+F7 (my "main" X server is running on vt7) and run `gdb my_app`. In gdb i run `set environment DISPLAY=:1` and can debug an app. `DISPLAY=:1 gdb my_app` also works. I can switch between servers with Ctrl+Alt+F7 / Ctrl+Alt+F8. I don't know why in Ubuntu second instance of X kills "main" instance, sorry.

Comment: @dimich So you start a new X from your graphical interface on vt7, and give it the vt8? That's neat, I'll need to try that. Although I think it will kill my first X.

Comment: @telcoM I don't think my application does anything more fancy that moving windows around and fetching input, it's a fork of git://git.suckless.org/dwm. Also, I can run then in parallel with different VT with startx, but I'm not sure if that starts another server. My understanding was that it must be different servers since in different VT, but not sure about that anymore.

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, it works for me. Currently i have Nvidia GTX 1660S and proprietary driver 515.76, but it worked with older card and drivers too.

Comment: @dimich Will, from my original graphical session, in a term emulator, I get this `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely on my Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot start a second X server with `X :1 vt3 &`, without crashing my first server.

I can start it with `startx`, though.

---

My current solution:

In `~/.xinitrc`:

```
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR && xhost +local: && tail -f /dev/null
```

`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` for not mixing files, `xhost` for allowing a program in my other VT to output to the new VT, `tail` to wait while doing nothing.

In a new VT (VT3), I can now login and start an X server with `startx`.

Then in my first VT (VT2), I can check the `DISPLAY` variable of my other VT with the command `w`, and run gdb with my application:

```
DISPLAY=:1 gdb ./my_app
```

---

This definitely feels like a work-around. There must be a way to start a new X server without killing the first one, with `X`. But this seems functional enough for now.